# Order of assignment while setting Child LWC properties and calling child methods from a parent

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

From  "Fields, Properties, and Attributes" section of [LWC.dev guide](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript)    :"An attribute in HTML turns into a property assignment in JavaScript. In both cases, the order of assignment is not guaranteed."

```
<template>
<example-datatable selected-rows="1,2" rows="1,2,3,4"></example-datatable>
```

My question is : What is actually meant by order of assignment? Does that mean , in the child component, it is not guaranteed if selectedRows get set first or rows get set first? I'm assuming that is the case.  Am I right? Also document says, in "both" cases , anyone knows what are the two cases they referring to?  Making sure ground is covered before taking a dev approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is actually meant by order of assignment? Does that mean , in the child component, it is not guaranteed if selectedRows get set first or rows get set first?

Correct. Either selectedRows or rows may be set first.

> Also document says, in "both" cases, anyone knows what are the two cases they referring to?

Attributes (the things you set on HTML components) and properties (the values as they appear in the controller).

---

Basically, all of this is a warning that says you cannot rely on the value of any property or attribute marked `@api` in your component within a setter method. The values won't be "locked in" at that point.

This also means that you can't make certain assumptions about order of operations. For example:

```
export default class Sample extends LightningElement {
  _internal = [];
  @api set value1(value) {
    this._internal.push(value);
  }
  @api set value2(value) {
    this._internal.push(value);
  }
  get output() {
    return this._internal.map((v,i)=>({key:i,value:v}));
  }
}
```

---

```
<c-sample>
  <template for:each={output} for:item="value">
    <div key={value.key}>{value.value}</div>
  </template>
</c-sample>
```

Now, given:

```
<c-sample value1="5" value2="10"></c-sample>
```

The result can be either:

```
<div>5</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Or:

```
<div>10</div>
<div>5</div>
```

And it may technically vary simply by reloading the page. Only during life cycle hooks, such as connectedCallback and afterRender, can you safely assume all values are populated.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer and  the code attached  also  really helped me to better understand the getter setter concept in LWC. Coming from Java background( well defined use of get and set), it was difficult and confusing to comprehend it in LWC. In Java it is used to get and set the actual value of the param.  Here now I think it is to a) run a piece of code whenever a param's latest value is requested and b) to run a piece of code AFTER whenever/wherever a param's value is changed or set to a new value using that new value. The value of the param is not actually set in the setter.Thanks